# Multiple static TextViews VS Listview of TextView VS One TextView with multiple lines

Tags: android, listview, textview

Let say I have 10 text items which all of them will be visible to user. Each text item comes with a different color and style. I don't know what is the best approach to achieve this.

Multiple static textviews
    - easiest to implement, but performance may be the worst.

listview of textview
    - with all item visible to user, I'm not sure whether it is exactly similar to multiples static textviews in term of performance or not.

multiple lines
    - hardest to implement, not sure whether this approach can have 1 text item with 2 lines.

Can anyone suggest me? Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about 10 `TextView` performance problem. Unless your writing a book in them. If you really want to know which is performance-wise you can benchmark them with 1000 or more. But most likely inflating it with XML and retrieving  from XML should be the best performance-wise. Do what is easiest for your , or best for user.

Answer (score 0):

First decide what you want to implement.

**10 textView**

using this approach is fix with this activity only. and u can't use this it's very memory consume process.

**Listview of Textview**

use this approach it's  good and display every different color text then take any array of color fill with as you want to display.

Third one is very dole.

Answer (score 0):

If its fix that there will be only 10 `TextView` then use 10 `TextView`.

else if nos of `TextView` is not fixed use **[ListView](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/)**